# How to generate Keyhash (Facebook) using the Keytool in android for W7 32bit

Tags: android, facebook

I tried to generate the Keyhash for integrating the Facebook in our app, but when i generated the keyhash through cmd prompt, it can't generate.

```
C:\Users\DON\.android>keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.an
    droid/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

> 'keytool' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>       operable program or batch file.

and another command I use is:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\bin>keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey
     -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

> 'openssl' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>           operable program or batch file.

What is the problem?

Comment: first search for the keytool app in your s/m and navigate to that directory and use the command

Comment: Sir @droidhot i can not understand please could u exlpain

Comment: 'keytool' is not recognized as an internal or external command,  shows that C:\Users\DON.android> does not contain keytool.exe

Comment: @droidhot ,sir how to get this keytool.exe in our .android folder

Comment: copy paste or simply search for it and use the command from that folder hope and note ~ should be also suplied with the correct location

Comment: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\bin>keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey
     -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
this is were you have the keystore i hope extract this code into the folder
http://code.google.com/p/openssl-for-windows/downloads/detail?name=openssl-0.9.8k_WIN32.zip

Comment: sir @droidhot i had already download and extract this file in my c drive . I extract this file in right or wrong where i extract this file .

Comment: refer qtn http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506392/how-to-create-android-facebook-key-hash

Comment: just run your app and click to login in facebook ..the keyhash automatically generate in your logcat..

Comment: yes @MandeepPasbola , read the below answers

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using this command first download this file http://code.google.com/p/openssl-for-windows/downloads/detail?name=openssl-0.9.8k_WIN32.zip . Then extract the file and run this command:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\bin>keytool -export -alias myAlias -keystore C:\Users\DON\.android\myKeyStore | C:\openssl\bin\openssl sha1 -binary | C:\openssl\bin\openssl enc -a -xtIm30l*********=
```

**DON is my system name and should be replaced with your system name.**

Comment: In case it says:
unknown option '-xtlm301*********='.

It worked by replacing with base64 at the end.
keytool -export -alias myAlias -keystore C:\DON\.android\myKeyStore | C:\openssl\bin\openssl sha1 -binary | C:\openssl\bin\openssl base64
@Rishi Gautam -- Thanks !! saved my day.

Answer (score 9):

1. Download the [openssl-for-windows](https://code.google.com/p/openssl-for-windows/downloads/detail?name=openssl-0.9.8k_WIN32.zip) package.
2. Extract the zip.
3. In windows, edit the **path system variable** that points to `<openssl-extracted-folder>/bin`
4. Then run the command.

Comment: hi Mushtaq, can you please explain to me how can i edit the path. im stack. please help me

Comment: Hi @AndroidEnthusiast you can follow this to set the path variables https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will try this later. sorry Mushtaq, Im not good in terminal :D

Comment: @AndroidEnthusiast Hey no need for apologies, hope this helps

Answer (score 4):

First do the Facebook sdk setup then main program if you add this, you will get keyhash at console

There will be chances of 3 type keys once is debug and another is release key and after upload google changes signature ,you can provide all these 3 keys to facebook developer account ,then you  can check facebook login. depending upon your app mode facebook will match the key.Use toast to see the keyhash ,if you dont know android monitor from android studio

```
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLogger;

import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
   printKeyHash();
}


private void printKeyHash() {
    try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.i("KeyHash:",
                    Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
        }
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("jk", "Exception(NameNotFoundException) : " + e);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        Log.e("mkm", "Exception(NoSuchAlgorithmException) : " + e);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

it's late answer but it will help to lazy people like me.. add this code to your Application class, there is no need to download openssl and no need to set the path.. only need is just copy my code.. and keyHash will generated in log.

```
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
        printKeyHash();
    }

    private void printKeyHash() {
        try {
            PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                    getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
            for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                Log.i("KeyHash:",
                        Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
            }
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("jk", "Exception(NameNotFoundException) : " + e);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            Log.e("mkm", "Exception(NoSuchAlgorithmException) : " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

and do not forget add MyApplication class in manifest:

```
<application
        android:name=".application.MyApplication"
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Download openssl from https://code.google.com/archive/p/openssl-for-windows/downloads.

Extract the file and then execute in CMD, replancing the routes and the KeyName

```
keytool -exportcert -alias KEYNAME -keystore "C:\Users\YOUR_USER\.android\debug.keystore" 
| "C:\URL_OPENSSL_EXTRACTED\bin\openssl" sha1 -binary 
| "C:\URL_OPENSSL_EXTRACTED\bin\openssl" base64.
```