# Facebook Auth only works from Webview

Tags: android, facebook, webview

My application asks for facebook authorization and so it was working fine with webview. I haven't install fb on my android device. Using fbsdk 3.5

Just to test fb application auth flow, I downloaded fb android application and logged in successfully.

Then I tried my app to use android fb app auth instead of webview but it fails with this error

```
Bad thing happened UnknownError: ApiException:Key hash pBc2****************MwM does not match any stored key hashes.
```

I uninstall fb android app and tried doing auth using webview it worked.

FB app auth gave me error on first time here is trace

```
    01-31 14:22:32.129: W/Bundle(3897): Key com.facebook.platform.protocol.PROTOCOL_VERSION expected String but value was a java.lang.Integer.  The default value <null> was returned.
01-31 14:22:32.149: W/Bundle(3897): Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
01-31 14:22:32.149: W/Bundle(3897): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
01-31 14:22:32.149: W/Bundle(3897):     at android.os.Bundle.getString(Bundle.java:1069)
01-31 14:22:32.149: W/Bundle(3897):     at android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(Intent.java:4768)
01-31 14:22:32.149: W/Bundle(3897):     at com.facebook.AuthorizationClient$KatanaLoginDialogAuthHandler.tryAuthorize(AuthorizationClient.java:821)
01-31 14:22:32.149: W/Bundle(3897):     at com.facebook.AuthorizationClient.tryCurrentHandler(AuthorizationClient.java:272)
01-31 14:22:32.149: W/Bundle(3897):     at com.facebook.AuthorizationClient.tryNextHandler(AuthorizationClient.java:238)
01-31 14:22:32.149: W/Bundle(3897):     at com.facebook.AuthorizationClient$GetTokenAuthHandler.getTokenCompleted(AuthorizationClient.java:772)
01-31 14:22:32.149: W/Bundle(3897):     at com.facebook.AuthorizationClient$GetTokenAuthHandler$1.completed(AuthorizationClient.java:731)
01-31 14:22:32.149: W/Bundle(3897):     at com.facebook.internal.PlatformServiceClient.callback(PlatformServiceClient.java:144)
01-31 14:22:32.149: W/Bundle(3897):     at com.facebook.internal.PlatformServiceClient.handleMessage(PlatformServiceClient.java:128)
01-31 14:22:32.149: W/Bundle(3897):     at com.facebook.internal.PlatformServiceClient$1.handleMessage(PlatformServiceClient.java:54)
01-31 14:22:32.149: W/Bundle(3897):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-31 14:22:32.149: W/Bundle(3897):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-31 14:22:32.149: W/Bundle(3897):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5283)
01-31 14:22:32.149: W/Bundle(3897):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-31 14:22:32.149: W/Bundle(3897):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-31 14:22:32.149: W/Bundle(3897):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
01-31 14:22:32.149: W/Bundle(3897):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
01-31 14:22:32.149: W/Bundle(3897):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I dig up the fB sdk and this is what at line 821

```
Intent intent = NativeProtocol.createLoginDialog20121101Intent(context, request.getApplicationId(),
                new ArrayList<String>(request.getPermissions()),
                request.getDefaultAudience().getNativeProtocolAudience());
        if (intent == null) {
            return false;
        }
```

and here is createLoginDialog20121101Intent

```
public static Intent createLoginDialog20121101Intent(Context context, String applicationId, ArrayList<String> permissions,
        String audience) {
    Intent intent = new Intent()
                .setAction(INTENT_ACTION_PLATFORM_ACTIVITY)
                .setPackage(FACEBOOK_PACKAGE)
                .addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT)
                .putExtra(EXTRA_PROTOCOL_VERSION, PROTOCOL_VERSION_20121101)
                .putExtra(EXTRA_PROTOCOL_ACTION, ACTION_LOGIN_DIALOG)
                .putExtra(EXTRA_APPLICATION_ID, applicationId)
                .putStringArrayListExtra(EXTRA_PERMISSIONS, ensureDefaultPermissions(permissions))
                .putExtra(EXTRA_PROTOCOL_CALL_ID, generateCallId())
                .putExtra(EXTRA_WRITE_PRIVACY, ensureDefaultAudience(audience));
    return validateKatanaActivityIntent(context, intent);
}
```

EDIT: Also tried Facebook SDK 3.6 didn't help

I don't find anything suspicious here. Need help to sort this out.

Thanks.

Comment: you need to create hashkey and put that key in your facebook app settings to work your app with installed fb account.

Comment: just look at this link for more info : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506392/how-to-create-android-facebook-key-hash/18101444#18101444

Comment: @Biraj As already mentioned that it is working with webview which means everything has been setup properly.

Comment: No dude that is your miss understanding. Webview does not requires hash authentication. But when you try to authenticate/longin through installed app it must  requires. If you notice error it says "hash pBc2****************MwM does not match any stored key hashes."

Comment: @Biraj didn't know that. Let me try and will get back to you. thanks.

Comment: Are you running on linux machine or windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For Linux**

Open Terminal :

**For Debug Build**

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

you wil find **debug.keystore** from ".android" folder copy it from and paste on desktop and run above command

**For release Build**

```
keytool -exportcert -alias <aliasName> -keystore <keystoreFilePath> | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

**NOTE : Make sure In Both case it must ask for password. If it does not asks for password that means something is wrong in command.**

Now go to 
-> https://developers.facebook.com

-> Click on "**Apps**"

-> Select Your App

-> Click on "**Settings**" on left tab

-> Under "**Android**" Section you will find input field "**Key Hashes**"

-> Put the generated **hashkey** there and save changes.

Comment: I know it is little late :). But just gave it a try yesterday and it worked.