# Android Facebook SDK : "(# 404) Keyhash XXXXXX does not match any stored key hashes"

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-keystore

I am trying Android Facebook integration for an app. I am new to this.

I have got the Facebook SDK & I am trying to run a few samples from there. When I run the samples I get this error " (# 404) Keyhash XXXXXX does not match any stored key hashes ".

The XXXXXX is probably my keyhash, I did some basic search about what it is. I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506392/how-to-create-android-facebook-key-hash) and I compared the XXXXXX value with the Java Keytool.exe from my machine. There was a match with these numbers.

I have to get this working - I feel I have to add this somewhere on Facebook developer site. Can someone tell me if thats correct & also how to do it. OR my approach may be wrong too, if you can guide me to the correct approach. That will be helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: You have to add this hashkey in the facebook developer console of your app.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming that you know how to create a hash key, I suggest you to follow the below steps to add a hash key in `FaceBook` developer console of your app,

**1.** After creating a app, click on settings from the left side panel.

**2.** Select add platform.

**3.** From the pop up, select Android as your platform.

**4.** There you will find fields to enter Package Name, Class Name, and hash Keys.

**5.** Fill up the respective fields.You can enter many hash keys as well.

**Note** : If you enter wrong hash key, then it will show you the same error again.

hope it helps.

Answer (score 14):

After spending few hours and referring few answers here. finally its worked for me. few observations:

1. hashcode generated by Keytool is not same as hashcode showing in exception. Use the later one.
2. For Facebook Sample apps we need to add the hash for SampleApp.Here if we entered the hash and click on SaveChanges its clearing and not saved.So before clicking the SaveChanges need to hit the enter key and make sure its not clearing.
3. need to append = at the end of hashkey shown in exception.

Comment: #1 may be wrong. The keytool one works for me. My problem was I was in a hurry, so I had not filled in package name

Comment: Ug!  Adding the = after the hash in the error was the key.

Comment: You can get the hashcode shown in the exception by adding a snippet of code as described here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/#troubleshooting

Answer (score 1):

While generating release Hash key, Note this

**Windows:**
When generating the hash key for production you need to use `openssl-0.9.8e_X64.zip` on windows, you cannot use `openssl-0.9.8k_X64.zip`

The versions produce different hash keys, for some reason 9.8k does not work correctly... 9.8e does.

OR

Use this below flow

This is how I solved this problem
Download your APK to your PC in java jdk\bin folder
in my case `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_121\bin`
go to java `jdk\bin` folder and run cmd then
copy the following command in your cmd

`keytool -list -printcert -jarfile yourapkname.apk`

Copy the SHA1 value to your clip board
like this `CD:A1:EA:A3:5C:5C:68:FB:FA:0A:6B:E5:5A:72:64:DD:26:8D:44:84`
and open [Hex To Base 64](http://tomeko.net/online_tools/hex_to_base64.php) to convert your SHA1 value to base64.

**For MAC**

Step 1:

Generate SHA1 key by using below command
keytool -list -v -keystore 
Enter Keystore password.
Copy SHA1 Key.

Step 2:
Open this link - [Hex To Base 64](http://tomeko.net/online_tools/hex_to_base64.php)
Paste the SHA1 Key in Hex String
Click convert button
Get the Release Keyhash in Output value

Answer (score 0):

In addition to being aware of hash issues, you also need to make sure that the Facebook account on the device is an admin account, develop account or an account that has permission to participate in the test.

Comment: It appears you have written the same answer in 2 different languages - SO is a english-only site. Could you remove any other languages?