# FacebookSDK for Android: What is the reason behind two different key hashes?

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I have followed this [article](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share).
I generated the key hash for testing the `facebook sdk for android` samples following the instructions from [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started). They worked perfectly. I have added that same key hash in the facebook developer console page for an android app I am developing. I am getting this error while trying to publish a post(See image):

[image]

The problem is, that key hash is not the same as the one I obtained following the steps mentioned in the `Getting Started with the Facebook SDK for Android` page. The answer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22244176/android-facebook-sdk-404-keyhash-xxxxxx-does-not-match-any-stored-key-has) is not appicable because I have already followed those steps while following the instructions in the `Getting Started with the Facebook SDK for Android` page.

In one [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23349386/2940727) in that same post I found that the person noticed the difference between the two keys but, in the comments another person expressed doubt. Even if I want use the key hash shown in the Error `Toast` with an `=` sign, how can I print it in the `LogCat`?
Currently I see only this in the `LogCat` :

```
Error: com.facebook.FacebookException: Error publishing message
```

**onActivityResult**:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data, new FacebookDialog.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookDialog.PendingCall pendingCall, Exception error, Bundle data) {
                Log.e("Activity", String.format("Error: %s", error.toString()));
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete(FacebookDialog.PendingCall pendingCall, Bundle data) {
                Log.i("Activity", "Success!");
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: I have been able to get the Key Hash programmatically by using a modified version of the code provided in second `Troubleshooting` section of the `Getting Started` page, but the confusion about two Key Hashes remains.

Comment: Are you using code for generating the Key hash or you are using terminal ?