# Ionic Facebook invalid key hash

Tags: facebook, ionic3

I can't get my app to allow Facebook login. Everytime the users tries to login to Facebook and authenticate my app with their FB, it gives this error

**Invalid key hash. They key hash xxxxxxxxxx= does not match any stored key hashes. configure your app key hashes at http://developers.facebook.com/apps/xxxxxxxx**

I've already tried creating a new key hash through the OpenSSL tool like so:

**keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %HOMEPATH%.android\debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64**

I am facing this issue since 3 days and no result so for ,can some one help me please

Comment: try this to get hash of unsigned Apk -> keytool -list -printcert -jarfile <your apk>

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22244373/8850397 may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Following steps solved my problem

Go to facebook account inside settings > Apps and Websites > Logged in with Facebook > Active > click on ur app > And Remove App 2: After doing that try to login now and this time you will get facebook error code 1349195 : something like go to facebook docs/android page and do the setting 3:Now run the command from yours teminal

```
keytool -list -printcert -jarfile yourapkname.apk
```

Copy the SHA1 value and convert that into base64 and paste that base64 value into you facebook account and then try login.