# Android KeyHash Valid when Debug, Invalid when I install the App from APK

Tags: android, facebook, hash, authentication, key

I got KeyHash using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6665263/4543067).
Of course, I copied this (KeyHash, package name and main activity class) to facebook settings [according this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started#release-key-hash).

And when I debug my app it looks fine (I can login and logout how many times I want), but when I create APK and run the app I received common error "invalid key hash the key hash does not match any stored key hash..."

What do I need to except getting right KeyHash and adding it into your Facebook App ID's Android settings?

Comment: When you create an APK, typically you're using a different keystore than your debug keystore, so you're going to have a different key hash as well. You need to add that key hash to your developer settings as well.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that KeyHash is different. No I used command: "keytool -exportcert -alias <name_of_jks_file> -keystore "C:\Users\Beata\AndroidStudioProjects\<app_name>\APK" | "C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl" sha1 -binary | "C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl" base64". But still KeyHash is invalid. Did I use good this <name_of_jks_file> ?

Comment: The easiest way is to do it in code, and print it out in logcat. If you're using v4 of the SDK, you can just call FacebookSdk.getApplicationSignature(context)

Comment: How to call FacebookSdk.getApplicationSignature(context)? I receive null when I call it.

Comment: Can you post some code samples? If you're calling it from an activity, you should just call FacebookSdk.getApplicationSignature(this);

Comment: Thank you for your help. I solved the problem with keyhash for apk at last.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to call

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
```

before calling

```
FacebookSdk.getApplicationSignature(getApplicationContext());
```

to **avoid** getting **`NULL`**

This worked fine for me.

Comment: Please @Vishnuvathsan , I need you help on the project you help me with. 
Can you please send me the source code files you have on Fiverr? 
I hope you are feeling well!