# Facebook Generate Keyhash for Android

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio

I'm having trouble with the conventional way of generating a keyhash in fb, 
which requires openssl and a lengthy process...

I was wondering if I could just type in 28 random characters and use that string as my keyhash? .

Comment: that will not work, you have to generate key hash..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create Android Facebook Key Hash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506392/how-to-create-android-facebook-key-hash)

Comment: The keyhash is not some random number you type in and get on with life.No offense but in the time it took you to write this and wait for an answer, you could have gone through one of these [lenghty processes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306009/facebook-android-generate-key-hash?lq=1)

Comment: no @y.feizi I was asking if random numbers will work, so it is not a duplicate

Comment: you can use a tool that i built for ios and windows http://stackoverflow.com/a/17732453/2226605 and upvote my answer there if that helped you. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
           try {
              PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                "yourpackagename", 
                PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.e("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(),Base64.DEFAULT));
            }
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

    }
```

Comment: Log.e("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(),Base64.DEFAULT)); will print your keyhash cpy it and paste in our fb app settings

Comment: you can put this code anywhere is your app but i will recommend to put it in your first activity  and  then you will get a log in your logcat  copy the keyhash and then paste it in your facebook settings and then you are done

Answer (score 0):

```
//Call this method for KeyHash  
    String keyHash = getKeyHashForFacebook(SplashScreen.this);
    Log.e("keyHash  ", keyHash);


    public static String getKeyHashForFacebook(Context context) {
            try {
                PackageInfo info = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                        context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
                for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                    md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                    return "KeyHash:" + context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + "=>"
                            + Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();

            }
            return "=>";
        }
```

@fuad check this out for Logcat http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html ![check Logcat for KeyHash [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aF77n.jpg)

[image]

[image: Logcat]