# keytool return a hash that too short for facebook

Tags: android, facebook, openssl, single-sign-on, keytool

I use Window 7 with android studio to build my application.
I used in facebook SSO for the login system. I follow the steps
as the below tutorial.

[How to create Android Facebook Key Hash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506392/how-to-create-android-facebook-key-hash)

I inputted the command as below into my powershell

> $ keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator.android\debug.keystore" | "C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl" sha1 -binary |"C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl" base64

Then the powershell return a hash shorter than 28 chars, which is not accepted by facebook.

How can I generate a key accepted by facebook?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this hashkey generated by below code:

```
public static void printHashKey(Context pContext) {
    try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageInfo(pContext, PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            String hashKey = new String(Base64.encode(md.digest(), 0));
            Log.i(TAG, "printHashKey() Hash Key: " + hashKey);
        }
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "printHashKey()", e);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "printHashKey()", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: just add this to your main activity's onCreate. you will get haskey in log.@Chi-YoungJeffreyLii

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem when I provided invalid keystore path - no error message, just strange eight-character-long string. Switching path to

```
C:\Users\Username.android\debug.keystore
```

solved the problem in my case.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me when i use openssl-0.9.8k_WIN32.zip,generated only TenDigitHash== then i returned to using openssl-0.9.8e_WIN32.zip so it generated hash as expected. I am using windows32bit