# Before sign apk fb sdk work but after sign apk not work

Tags: android, facebook

When i have run application in mobile face book sdk work fine but when i create sign apk what wrong with this it show hash key not match `onError` method of facebook what to do now please help me out. i worked on it since last night.

Comment: you have to generate signed hash key and put it facebook developer account..

Comment: how i will get that one please suggest me

Comment: look this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506392/how-to-create-android-facebook-key-hash

Comment: i was create this and put in facebook developer console so it work normaly for unsign apk  but when i generate sign apk , and install in mobile at that time fb account not work and show hask key not match

Comment: After signing apk ,print hash key and put it .

Comment: how to print hash key because i generate sign apk in log cat no hash key present even thought i write logic in oncreate activity

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106806/discussion-between-kirti-and-rajan1404930).