# Spring boot 2.0 Web client block execution hold application

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I move my application to use spring-boot 2.0.0.RELEASE, and logic with WebClient stop working.

```
String resp =  WebClient.create("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506392/how-to-create-android-facebook-key-hash").get().retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(String.class)
            .block();

log.info(resp);
```

When this code execute application just hold

Important thing with 2.0.0.RC2 its working

What it can be ? thanks

Comment: I guess it is a bug in one of the Spring Boot dependencies. If it really works with RC2 and not with RELEASE, you should open a bug report at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues.

Comment: Did you find the solution?