# key Hash mismatch for signed apk

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I'm integrated facebook login in my app and the **key hash created for production using release .jks play store signin file** and  generated keyhash added in fb console and no other key hash added. now when i try to login using fb login it gives error:

**Invalid key hash**. The key hash xxxxfgxxxdfdsxxx= does not match any stored key hashes.  Configure your app key hashes at https://developers.facebook.com/apps/xxxxx7xx4xxxx/

and above (xxxxfgxxxdfdsxxx=) given key hash is not even in my fb developer console.

Comment: add that given xxxxfgxxxdfdsxxx= key hash in your facebook console. it will work.

Comment: ok. but by whom/from where this key hash is generated? and can it safe to add that key hash for my application in developer console?

Comment: Please look at my updated answer below. In 2nd method it generates key hash from an app using package signature and it's safe

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but looking Facebook needs 2 key hashes,

1) we create using `.jks` file release key hash,

```
keytool -exportcert -alias <RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS> -keystore <RELEASE_KEY_PATH> | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

and

2) it also shows us in device that (xxxxxxxxxx=) key doesn't match in your key hashes.

It uses this method in your activity.

```
public void getHashkey(){
    try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());

            Log.i("Base64", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(),Base64.NO_WRAP));
        }
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        Log.d("Name not found", e.getMessage(), e);

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        Log.d("Error", e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

So when we enter both key hashes. It works perfectly.

Comment: Great. Accept this answer so other can also get this if they have issues in future.

Comment: Key hashes generated through command prompt and the above method getKeyHash  are different? if yes how?

Comment: I am also searching it for a long but I didn't found it and so I enter both keys everytime.

Comment: Please refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506392/how-to-create-android-facebook-key-hash/25524657#25524657  this will answer your question and Please don't forget to Accept answer and vote up