# Ionic 3 | Facebook Native not working after building --release android

Tags: android, ionic3, facebook-login

I recently followed these instructions to build an app which I published on Google Play. After finishing, the Facebook Login no longer works. I get the `Key hash xxxxxxxxxxx= does not match any stored key hashes`. I added this hash to Facebook, but still getting the same message. I even generated a new hash following this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/18101444/385623 and nothing. What can be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case after publishing the app to Google Play I was able to to to find the SHA-1 fingerprint (which I also copied to `Firebase > Project settings > Android app` as well)

In the Google Play Console: `Release management > App signing` find the `SHA-1 certificate fingerprint` then use this http://tomeko.net/online_tools/hex_to_base64.php to convert it. Save the `Output (base64)` to your Facebook app and it should work. It did for me.

Comment: Does it mean that I could publish my apk to Google Play only building it as a release (with no key hash), and after that, just find the new SHA-1 from Google Play, copy it to Firebase and also convert it into base64 (to inform into Facebook settings)?