# Unexpected token 'sha1' in expression or statement. For Generating keyhash for facebook developer account app

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to generate key hash for app in which I have integrate facebook sign in

For generationg keyhash I am using code beloew as per facecook document

```
> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin> keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\Akash\.android \debug.keystore" |"C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl" sha1 -binary | "C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl" base64
```

but it shows me error like:

```
At line:1 char:97
+ ... ers\Akash\.android\debug.keystore" | "C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl" sha1 -b ...
+                                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline.
At line:1 char:122
+ ... kash\.android\debug.keystore" | "C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl" sha1 -binary ...
+                                                              ~~~~
Unexpected token 'sha1' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:137
+ ... :\OpenSSL\bin\openssl" sha1 -binary | "C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl" base64
+                                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline.
At line:1 char:162
+ ... :\OpenSSL\bin\openssl" sha1 -binary | "C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl" base64
+                                                                    ~~~~~~
Unexpected token 'base64' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
```

Comment: I hope that you first downloaded _OpenSSL_ tool. Then did you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506392/how-to-create-android-facebook-key-hash)?

Comment: I was generating keyhash in PowerShell of windows, Then I tried in command prompt and it worked.

Comment: So now its working now?

Comment: yes, its working now

Comment: Okay Nice..........

Answer (score 11):

Use Command Prompt. It will work.

Answer (score 1):

use cmd and try this code below. It Worked for me

1.First download and install openssl (from git if possible)
2.set environment variable for openssl and java and try this

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "%USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore" | "openssl" sha1 -binary | "openssl" base64
```

If it ask for password use **android**

Answer (score -1):

Don't use the terminal inside the Visual Studio Code or Android Studio, use PowerShell or a standard Command Prompt.