# How to integrate login with Linked-in in android studio

Tags: java, android, linkedin-api

i want to integrate login with linked in i have created app on linked developers account i have follow some tutorials but when i go to my app which i created i cant find Hash key and package name for android to connect this app to my application in android studio Can please someone tell me what should i do now [Screenshot of Developer account of Tutorials i followed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJckw.png)

This is my Developer Account Screen

[Screenshot of My Developer account of linked-in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMegr.png)

in Setting Tab i can only edit name description can someone tell how can i connect my app to linked app. i have already downloaded linked-in SDK and import it to my android studio 
Thanks in Advance

Comment: In package name add your `application Id`  from `build.gradle` file . See documentation to  generate key hash https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/android-sdk . For step by step tutorial to generate key hash see my answer over here https://stackoverflow.com/a/46241386/6478047

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create hash key from below code

```
 fun getPackageHash() {
        try {
            @SuppressLint("PackageManagerGetSignatures")
            val info = context.packageManager.getPackageInfo(
                    "your package name",//give your package name here
                    PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES)
            for (signature: Signature in info.signatures) {
                val md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA")
                md.update(signature.toByteArray())

                Log.d("LinkedInSignInManager", "Hash  : " + Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.NO_WRAP))//Key hash is printing in Log
            }
        } catch (e: PackageManager.NameNotFoundException) {
            Log.d("LinkedInSignInManager", e.message, e)
        } catch (e: NoSuchAlgorithmException) {
            Log.d("LinkedInSignInManager", e.message, e)
        }
    }
```

you can get your package name from your app's **build.gradle** file in that **applicationId** is your **package name**.

Add this both hash key and package name to link to your application