# Nativescript firebase plugin facebook authentication - Sign app in debug mode

Tags: angular, nativescript

I have successfully integrated Nativescript firebase plugin to enable facebook authentication. My FB login call looks like this:

```js
firebase.login({
    type: firebase.LoginType.FACEBOOK,
    // Optional
    facebookOptions: {
      // defaults to ['public_profile', 'email']
      scope: ['public_profile', 'email']
    }
  }).then(
      function (result) {
        JSON.stringify(result);
      },
      function (errorMessage) {
        console.log(errorMessage);
      }
  );
```

**Login fails with error** "Error while trying to login with Fb SERVER_ERROR: [code] 1349195 [message]: The key hash does not match any stored key hashes" which is evident because I haven't added Keyhash in Facebook app.

I was expecting a key hash value in the error message according to the [documentation](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase/blob/master/docs/AUTHENTICATION.md#android) so that I can add it in Facebook app.

I think the error message would have key hash only when the app is signed

**Issue**

- I have already spent hours without any luck figuring out how to sign the app in debug mode. I am running the app using the command 'tns debug android'
- I know it is possible to sign the app using '[tns run android](https://docs.nativescript.org/tooling/docs-cli/project/testing/run-android)' but it won't let me debug the app.

I think I am missing something tiny here - Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved it using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7506445/5468755). It turned out that it is important to keep extracted SSL folder in C drive.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the {N} [docs](https://docs.nativescript.org/tooling/publishing/publishing-android-apps#debug-certificate), the debug builds are signed by the debug keystore created and managed by Android itself.

If you refer the [official Android docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#debug-mode), you will know where these certificates are located.

> - `~/.android/` on OS X and Linux
> - `C:\Documents and Settings\user\.android\` on Windows XP
> - `C:\Users\user\.android\` on Windows Vista and Windows 7, 8, and 10

Comment: Alright, according to the docs debug builds are signed automatically. So that means error message should also have printed the key hash, right? I have also tried generating key hash manually `keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %HOMEPATH%.android\debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64` but the output looks invalid because it isn't 28 chars long.

Comment: I'm on Mac OS (10.14.4), it works perfectly fine for me, returns the 28 chars hash key.

Answer (score 0):

Just using NativeScript, You can find your facebook key hash by running logs with command `tns device log` or `tns device log --device <Device ID>`, if multiple devices are connected. Device ID is the device index or identifier as listed by the `tns device` command (source: https://docs.nativescript.org/tooling/docs-cli/device/device-log).

The facebook key hash is now visible in the logs in format `fb4a.BlueServiceQueue: X.2nk: [code] 404 [message]: Key hash <THIS_IS_YOUR_HASH> does not match any stored key hashes.` Just Ctrl+F `key hash` or similar in the terminal to find this log.

Last, paste the hash to Facebook developer console where you have created your Android app (*Basic* tab) next to *Google Play Package Name* field (nativescript id from your `package.json`) field and *Class name* field (`com.tns.NativeScriptActivity`). You don't need to have live app to try the Firebase Facebook auth, it works on development mode too.

[image]