# Mismatch key hash FBSDK

Tags: hash, react-native-fbsdk

I am getting this error when trying to login with facebook.

> The key hash does not match any stored key hashes.

I faced this similar error before but usually when this error appear, the facebook itself will show the key hash and what I do is just copy the key hash and register it in my facebook app. But the situation now is different because when I get the error above, I did not receive any key hash so I have no idea how to re-generate the key hash.

What I know is, you cannot use the command to re-generate another key hash for the second time like in the following code below.

`keytool -exportcert -alias YOUR_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS -keystore YOUR_RELEASE_KEY_PATH | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64`

For additional information just in case if this is related, the app is previously developed and the first key hash generated from other device. I copied the project and use another laptop to do the debugging. Just a guess, maybe this is one of the reason why the facebook app isn't showing the mismatch key hash?

Answer (score 0):

You can still generate the key hash with the command

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "your-release-key-path" | "your-openssl-path" sha1 -binary |"your-openssl-path" base64
```

You may want to check this post [How to create Android Facebook Key Hash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506392/how-to-create-android-facebook-key-hash)

Comment: Okay I've tried this and there is a key hash shown but after I register it to facebook app, the error is still showing key hash does not match.