# msalclientexception redirect URI does not match

Tags: android, azure, authentication, microsoft-graph-api, azure-authentication

I have to integrate Microsoft authentication API for login in the android app. for that I registered my app to the Azure portal, by providing a package name and Signature hash.
Signature hash is generated using this command
**keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %HOMEPATH%.android\debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64**

on app run, I'm getting this exception
**MsalClient Exception: The redirect URI does not match with the package name and signature hash.**
but both the package name and signature hash is the same at android and Azure. im following this tutorial
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-android

Comment: Hi did you have a chance to look into my update in comment under answer? Is it helpful?

Answer (score 0):

I test the [sample code](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-android-java/) and it works fine.

Make sure that you need to follow [this part](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-android-java/#register-your-own-application-optional) to configure your Azure AD app.

There are two files need to be configured: `AndroidManifest.xml` and `auth_config.json`.

My configuration for your reference:

**auth_config_multiple_account.json**

```
{
  "client_id" : "6cXXXXa2-295d-455a-88fe-b1XXXXXXXX0e",
  "authorization_user_agent" : "DEFAULT",
  "redirect_uri" : "msauth://com.azuresamples.msalandroidapp/1wIqXSqBj7w%2Bh11ZifsnqwgyKrY%3D",
  "authorities" : [
    {
      "type": "AAD",
      "audience": {
        "type": "AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount",
        "tenant_id": "common"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<data
                    android:host="com.azuresamples.msalandroidapp"
                    android:path="/1wIqXSqBj7w+h11ZifsnqwgyKrY="
                    android:scheme="msauth" />
```

**Azure AD app**

[image]

Comment: @iSevaDigital You need to specify the path.  My example for your reference: `keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "E:\Programs\ms-identity-android-java-master\gradle\debug.keystore" | "C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl" sha1 -binary | "C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl" base64`

Comment: @iSevaDigital You can also refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506392/how-to-create-android-facebook-key-hash.